# Using 8 6 4 2, how do you get to 30

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

8 6 4 2 =30 in that order using only + - X

Comment: Where did you get this question from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is:

> $ 8 + 6 \times 4 - 2 = 30 $